# SDL window not respondig

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

My SDL window crashes when clicking or minimizes it, the background is white and the OpenGL does not update the screen more. Follows the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const char * SCREEN_NAME = "Tetris SDL";

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_GLContext glcontext;

int init();
void main_loop();
void quit();
void events();
void update();
void draw();

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if(!init())
        quit();
    main_loop();
    quit();
}

int init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
       return 0;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE, 0);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(SCREEN_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(!window)
        return 0;

    glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    return 1;

}
void main_loop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        events();
        update();
        draw();
        //only for test
        SDL_Delay(16);
    }
}
void events(){}
void update(){}
void draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1,0,0); glVertex2f(0.0f,0.5f);
    glColor3f(0,1,0); glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(0,0,1); glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    glEnd();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
void quit()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glcontext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I'm using SDL 2.0 and GNU GCC compiler and Windows XP. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't handle any events while in the loop.

If you don't do that then the event of minimizing will not be handled (usually means the window buffer is freed to be use by someone else).

Comment: That's reason to stop the application?
I know it is essential the use of events, more halting the application because of it's kind of weird.

Comment: The OS sends all kind of event that all need to be handled. Usually a non responsive program continues to run but the OS will provide an option to kill it to the user. That you don't see anything is probably because a repaint event didn't get handled